# roslaunch does not work but rusrun does

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When starting my node "test_node" from the package "test_pck" with rosrun, everything works fine. Now i have written following launchfile named test.launch which i have placed in src/launch/

```
<launch>
<group ns="test">
  <node pkg="test_pck" name="test_name" type="test_node"/>
</group>
</launch>
```

however if i run "roslaunch test_pck test.launch" i gett following error in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
import roslaunch
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from .scriptapi import ROSLaunch
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
import roslaunch.parent
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 54, in <module>
import roslaunch.server
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 78, in <module>
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from ._Log import *
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/_Log.py", line 7, in <module>
import std_msgs.msg
ImportError: No module named msg
```

The terminal output of `rospack find std_msgs` is `/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_msgs`

I have absolutely now clue what i can do in order to solve this problem. Thank you for every hint!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200153/roslaunch-does-not-work-but-rusrun-does/) by [Rufio](https://answers.ros.org/users/20729/rufio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-29**:
Do you have `std_msgs` package installed? And edit your question with this command's output: `` ls -l `rospack find std_msgs`/msg ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug in roslaunch; not in your launch file or your packages.

There are two things you can try to check if this is a bug in roslaunch:

- Try running roslaunch by itself: `roslaunch`. (It might fail or it might not, depending on how the imports are structured).
- Try running roscore: `roscore` . roscore uses parts of the roslaunch API, and I suspect it will fail in the same way.

If either of these commands gives you a similar stacktrace to the one you're getting now, then this is definitely a bug in roslaunch and should be reported on their bug tracker: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues

If both of those work, then it's more likely that there's some kind of error in your launch file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0